# How to find existing deb package corresponding to PyPI entry?

Tags: python, pypi, software-distribution, deb

PyPI has a lot of packages, and many of them do have deb-equivalents for specific Debian distributions. It usually happens by prepending `python-` or `python3-` to the name of the original package, possibly with some other changes like lowercasing, etc, but not always.

Is there are good way to establish PyPI -> Debian version X correspondence in an automatic way?

For example, given a `requirements.txt` file (or a result of running `pip freeze`), are there any tools to list Debian packages?

Maybe, there is some service, which can, given "PyPI name", returns search result for Debian? I am not that familiar with Debian tools, but maybe there is a tool, which automates it as part of some process Debian uses?

For example: [alembic](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/alembic) package. Source package is a basis to create python-prefixed packages. And description points to where it [was taken from](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/alembic/alembic_1.0.0-3.dsc). Then on PyPI there is [a page](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/1.0.0/#files) for specific version files (and maybe a metadata description somewhere).

Can't find it with googling as search results turn out a lot of how to do your very own package, which is a different topic.

The process so far is time-consuming and heavily manual, using `apt-file search -l` to query for packages containing certain files.

Comment: I would be surprised if there's any way to determine the correspondence - in fact, I would be surprised if a true correspondence actually exists for all such packages, in either direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1912

```
$ apt-file --package-only --regex search 'alembic\-.*\.egg\-info'
python-alembic
python3-alembic
$ apt-file --package-only --regex search 'setuptools\-.*\.egg\-info'
pypy-setuptools
python-setuptools
python3-setuptools
```

Not sure about the *regular expression*, most likely it can be improved a lot.

---

Short Python wrapper script as an example:

```
import argparse
import subprocess

import pkg_resources  # from 'setuptools'


def _main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)
    parser.add_argument(
        'requirements',
        metavar='requirements.txt',
        type=argparse.FileType('r'),
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #
    requirements = [
        requirement.project_name
        for requirement
        in pkg_resources.parse_requirements(args.requirements)
    ]
    print(requirements)
    #
    regex = r'({})\-.*\.egg\-info'.format(
        '|'.join(
            [
                requirement.replace('-', '_')
                for requirement
                in requirements
            ],
        ),
    )
    #
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        [
            'apt-file',
            '--package-only',
            '--regex',
            'search',
            regex,
        ],
    )
    print(output.decode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Comment: Thanks for regex. Otherwise it's already what I use (see the question). Does this mean there is no way?

Comment: Somehow I missed the info that you already use `apt-file`... Anyway, by looking with this kind of regular expression I believe it's a true one-to-one match. I doubt the Debian/Ubuntu packagers change the names of the of the projects so the `.egg-info` should really have the exact same name as on PyPI. Additionally it should be relatively easy to script, either in Shell or Python. Also I believe `apt` actually is written in Python and so it should be possible to do something like `import apt` and work from there, if it's a thing you're interested in.

Comment: `apt-file` is written in Perl, `apt` most likely in C. But in any case it's easy to organize that kind of script. How accurate it is - only practive will show.

Comment: There are some Python interfaces, but I didn't quite manage to get the info needed out of them. `apt-file` is a good bet, I wrote a short Python wrapper script out of curiosity...

Answer (score 2):

PyPI administrator here: to my knowledge there is no such tool. Python packages are often redistributed as Debian packages with little to no input from the original maintainers, and there is no guarantee of parity when this happens.

I'd be curious why you're preferring to use the redistributed Debian packages rather than the original Python packages. Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: (Speaking with my Debian hat on)  It depends on what you do with your system and distro. I love installing / uninstalling package with `apt`, including Python packages. Once installed, they upgrade, they get tests etc pp.  OTOH manual `pip` (or alike) installations tend to get stale on my machine.   As for "no such tool":  Indeed an issue. I do _much_ more work with R and CRAN, and bridged the two out of curiousity with RcppAPT. It let's R know what (CRAN) packages are in Debian. But approximately nobody uses it...

Comment: Debian team adds value in selecting the packages, pinning versions which work together. So my idea was to reuse that knowledge plus automatic security updates. And the majority of packages are already in deb format, so it's easier to package a handful of those which are not and have streamlined deployment with private deb repo (also good for security). Also if several applications are on the same host, there is no need to setup virtualenvs for each - and a lot of care needed to get bundles with binaries. Yes - also add recent setuptools trouble to this.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am not working with R, but I suspect it gets some "marketing" for the idea to start spreading. That is, that way needs to be known to masses to see if it's really does appeal or there is some way, which is always better. Bridging system and language+platform packaging is an old problem. Maybe, some superhero is yet to come and solve it in theory and practice.